# Win10 display settings 'Duplicate mode' interfering with monitor OSD

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am gamer/programmer on Windows 10 64 bit Pro edition who plays/works at **1920 x 1080** resolution with the need to minimize my game to get to windows which is running at the same resolution. I am using 2 insignia monitors in 'Duplicate' mode with a GTX 970 Nvidia Graphics GPU

The issue I am having is that my monitors are receiving a resolution switch signal each time I make the switch from game to desktop or vice versa, despite that the game is played in 1080p and that the desktop resolution is also 1080p.

To understand this further you should understand that when I normally change resolutions in Windows, my TV produces an OSD showing which resolution is in effect. While this is considered normal behavior for the TVs that I am using while switching resolutions are waking from sleep, it is not normal when the resolution is not actually changing and that the devices are already on. Here is a shot of the OSD that pops up when I switch to game in the same resolution as the desktop:

[image]

After doing some testing I came to realize that the issue does not happen on either monitor when **only one monitor is selected in the display settings** (either when `PC screen Only` or `Secondary screen only` are selected). If `Duplicate` mode is enabled the issue is persistent.

[image]

So what I would like to understand (and correct if possible), is how Windows 10 and my GPU are handling the different monitor setups. There must be some technical explanation for why my hardware (monitors) are behaving differently in these different Windows monitor modes. 
I would like to keep Duplicate mode enabled so I dont have to constantly switch between setups to accommodate this issue.

Comment: Full-screen games often change some display settings. This might be happening to you, although the parameter that you can see displayed is only the resolution which didn't change. Does this also happen when the game is running in windowed mode (if possible)?

Comment: no doesn't happen in widowed mode.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid Do you see this behavior in extended display mode? Also how many graphics cards doe your system have (any integrated ones?)

Comment: I have one GPU with both monitors attached to separate outputs of the card. Not sure about extended.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid By chance, just by chance do you have an integrated graphics card that comes with your chipset

Comment: @KalamalkaKid https://www.theverge.com/2020/4/21/21228261/graphics-card-how-to-find-windows-10-macos-integrated-dedicated-gpu

Comment: @SamThomas it says right in the post which card I have

Comment: Well the reason I asked is because when there is an integrated card involved, the desktop and associated elements run on it, but your game runs on the nvidia card so it is expected to see this switching when your game runs on full screen mode.

Comment: If there is an onboard card it is not showing up in my display adapters in Control Panel and there is nothing physically attached to it.

Answer (score 1):

Games often change some display settings in full-screen mode, but don't do
that in windowed mode.
They may change the resolution, but also other parameters of the
display that may interfere with their handling of it.
When the screens are in Duplicate mode, the changes propagate to both of them.

I believe that this is what is happening in your case.
Although the resolution didn't change, other parameters did, and the monitor
reacted by displaying the new settings. Unfortunately the on-screen display
is limited to only the resolution, so you have no way of knowing which
parameter the game changed that triggered the OSD.

When you minimized the game, it returned to windowed mode, so it reset the
screen to the previous settings, so triggering the OSD display.

The game might have some settings that may influence this behavior.
Or you may be able to right-click its `.exe`, select Properties
and change some of the settings in the Compatibility tab, perhaps fooling it
into behaving otherwise.

If you can't find anything, I don't know of any way of preventing the game
from changing the display parameters in this way.

Comment: This doesnt really give me any information to work with.

Comment: This explains what is happening, since you asked to understand. If by "work with" you mean "avoid", then my answer lists the steps that you can take from inside Windows. Reprogramming the monitor's firmware is out of the question.

Comment: Changing the settings of the game exe in the compatibility mode  settings had no effect on the problem (I tried all combinations of settings). I suspect this is not a game related issue, but more about how windows handles full screen games in the `duplicate` mode.

Comment: That's exactly the problem : monitor changes propagate from one to the other in this mode. Some games I used did pretty strong changes in full-screen mode, like changing color-depth and display theme, which had to be undone manually when the game crashed. They can't do that in windowed mode, where they need to conform to the current display mode, even if they then have some difficulties.

Comment: If the game for example changed the color mode of Windows from 32-bit to 24-bit, that would trigger the OSD, but you wouldn't see it in the message.

Comment: This is still an issue of how Windows is handing things differently in the various display modes. Why would those attributes you mentioned not affect the OSD in a different window mode?

Comment: In windowed mode the game cannot take liberties with the display, because this will also affect all the other apps. It can only do so in full-screen mode when it is the only app on display, and is supposed to return the previous display mode when it stops being full-screen (I had some games that didn't do that correctly).

Comment: I think I have answered your question, explained why this happens and answered all your comments. Leaving my answer downvoted and letting your bounty go to waste does not seem like the right choice.

Comment: you are correct that you that my bounty was wasted. I was waiting to see if anyone would be able to provide an answer that would help me resolve the issue, but alas, I did not specify this in the bounty *my bad*. I have upvoted your answer, but am still looking for a solution for my problem. Thanks for your efforts.